# Select IDs where all rows have the same value in another column

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

How can we construct a `SELECT` statement to select a results set when we are grouping by status and id but there is a third column?

Given a table where

```
ID  |   Status  |   Type
——————————————————————————
1   |   Started |   A
1   |   Done    |   B
1   |   Done    |   C
2   |   Started |   A
2   |   Done    |   B
2   |   Started |   C
3   |   Done    |   A
3   |   Done    |   B
3   |   Done    |   C
4   |   Started |   A
4   |   Started |   B
4   |   Started |   C
5   |   Done    |   A
5   |   Done    |   B
5   |   Done    |   C
```

Desired result:
Select Id’s with only status of all the types = done.

In above example select the result set would include only ID 3 & 5

```
3 | Done
5 | Done
```

Comment: Are you using Microsoft SQL Server or PostgreSQL, which database system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming:

- there can be any number of rows per `id`
- `status` is defined `NOT NULL`

This returns all IDs where all existing entries have `status = 'Done'`:

```
SELECT id
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY id
HAVING min(status) = max(status)
AND    min(status) = 'Done'
ORDER  BY id;  -- optional
```

All standard SQL.

Comment: I love this approach, as it can be extended to accommodate joins too. Is this an "abusive" use of min and max, or is there a more "just" way to express this in SQL? It feels like an unfair, clever hack - that I feel guilty to like.

Comment: @ybakos I hope telling you the query is completely legit will not curb your guilty pleasure. :) Can't think of a better way for this particular task.